# Giving automatic object names

Tags: java, object

I have a `JButton` which after every click it will create different class objects(I need to know the name of the objects) How can I create object name automatically ? Let's say I am having this class :

```
public class Car{
private String name ;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Car ( String nume ) {
    setNume(nume);
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Variables in Java cannot be created dynamically.

Comment: If you ever think to encounter a case where you need dynamic object names, you should better review/refactor/rethink your code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? By clicking the Button you create a new object, and now you want to keep track of the references, is that right?

Comment: Every time i click the button to create a new object of that class without giving it a name by myself

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following - not sure if this is what you have in mind:

```
Map<String,Car> name2car = new HashMap<>();

Car newCar = new Car( "Herbie" );
name2car.put( newCar.getName(), newCar );
```

You can retrieve any Car given its name, obtain all Car names,...